# Find high correlations in a large coefficient matrix

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, pearson-correlation

I have a dataset with 56 numerical features. Loading it to `pandas`, I can easily generate a [correlation coefficients matrix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html).

However, due to its size, I'd like to find coefficients higher (or lower) than a certain threshold, e.g. >0.8 or <-0.8, and list the corresponding pairs of variables. Is there a way to do it? I figure it would require selecting by value across all columns, then returning, not the row, but the column name and row index of the value, but I have no idea how to do either!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do `where` and `stack()`: this:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3))

coeff = df.corr()

# 0.3 is used for illustration 
# replace with your actual value
thresh = 0.3

mask = coeff.abs().lt(thresh)
# or mask = coeff < thresh

coeff.where(mask).stack()
```

Output:

```
0  2   -0.089326
2  0   -0.089326
dtype: float64
```

Output:

```
0  1    0.319612
   2   -0.089326
1  0    0.319612
   2   -0.687399
2  0   -0.089326
   1   -0.687399
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach will work if you're looking to also deduplicate the correlation results.

```
thresh = 0.8

# get correlation matrix
df_corr = df.corr().abs().unstack()

# filter
df_corr_filt = df_corr[(df_corr>thresh) | (df_corr<-thresh)].reset_index()

# deduplicate
df_corr_filt.iloc[df_corr_filt[['level_0','level_1']].apply(lambda r: ''.join(map(str, sorted(r))), axis = 1).drop_duplicates().index]
```